# How to split a path properly in PHP

Tags: php, path, split

What is the best way to do the following:

I get a path with an AJAX request

e.g. `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4`

I need to present it like this on my webpage:

```
dir1 >> dir2 >> dir3 >> dir4
```

each of them being html anchor tags with the href attribute being

```
/dir1

/dir1/dir2

/dir1/dir2/dir3

/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
```

respectively

What is the most elegant and efficient way to achieve this?

so far, I'm doing something like this which i think is really dirty:

```
<?php 
$dirs = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $this->metadata["path"]);
    foreach ($dirs as $key=>$val) {
             if ($val == '') {
                 continue;
             }
             $pathArray = array();
             for ($i = 0; $i <= $key; $i++) {
                 array_push($pathArray, $dirs[$i]);
             }
             $path = implode('/', $pathArray);
             echo " >> <a href=" . $path . ">" . truncate($val) . "</a>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Seems right to me (and not so dirty), although `truncate` function does not exist. Is it a custom function or did you mean `trim`?

Comment: its a custom function...so..u think its an elegant block of code?:)

Comment: Well, that's how I would do that. If that's elegant, then hoorray :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this maybe (if I got your intention right):

```
<?php
$str = 'dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4';

$output = array();
$chunks = explode('/', $str);
foreach ($chunks as $i => $chunk) {
    $output[] = sprintf(
        '<a href="#/%s">%s</a>',
        implode('/', array_slice($chunks, 0, $i + 1)),
        $chunk
    );
}

echo implode(' &gt;&gt; ', $output);
```

Output:

```
<a href="#/dir1">dir1</a> &gt;&gt; 
<a href="#/dir1/dir2">dir2</a> &gt;&gt;
<a href="#/dir1/dir2/dir3">dir3</a> &gt;&gt;
<a href="#/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4">dir4</a>
```

Comment: what about for differ file systems with different slashes?

Comment: @Sevenearths I don't see the relation to os specific file systems. But if need be, just use a different char other than `"/"` in the code.

Comment: windows its `\\ ` and unix `/` (or something like that)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this...

```
<?php

$path = 'dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4';
$dirs = explode('/', $path);

while (count($dirs) > 0) {
    $link = '/' . implode($dirs, '/');
    $text = array_pop($dirs);
    $breadcrumb = "<a href=\"$link\">$text</a>" . $breadcrumb;
    if (count($dirs) > 0) {
        $breadcrumb = ' &gt;&gt; ' . $breadcrumb;
    }
}

echo $breadcrumb;
```

If you are getting this path based on the URL you shouldn't need to use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` because URLs should always use `/`.  If it is derived from the filesystem path you would need to swap it in instead of `'/'` on line 4.

Comment: Thanks about the PATH_SEPARATOR .. i'm doing explode('/', $path) now:)

Comment: @user787124: note that `PATH_SEPARATOR` is not / or \ -- it is ; or : on Windows and Unix respectively. It is the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` that you might want to use.

Answer (score 1):

**Var 1**

```
<?php

    $str = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4';
    $arr = array_filter(explode('/',$str));
    $out = array('/'.implode('/',$arr).'/');
    while((array_pop($arr) and !empty($arr))){
        $out[] = '/'.implode('/',$arr).'/';
    };

    print_r($out);

    /*
    Array(
       [0] => /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
       [1] => /dir1/dir2/dir3/
       [2] => /dir1/dir2/
       [3] => /dir1/
    )
    */

?>
```

**Var 2 ( Links )**

```
<?php

    $str = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4';
    $arr = array_filter(explode('/',$str));
    $out = array('<a href="/'.implode('/',$arr).'/">'.basename($str).'</a>');
    while((array_pop($arr) and !empty($arr))){
        $out[] = '<a href="/'.implode('/',$arr).'/">'.end($arr).'</a>';
    };

    print_r($out);

    /*
    Array
    (
        [0] => <a href="/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/">dir4</a>
        [1] => <a href="/dir1/dir2/dir3/">dir3</a>
        [2] => <a href="/dir1/dir2/">dir2</a>
        [3] => <a href="/dir1/">dir1</a>
    )
    */

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if all you need to do is explode by forward slash there is a simple solution that works everytime.

check this out

```
$path = 'dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4';

$array = explode('/', ltrim($path, '/'));

print_r($array);
```

enjoy :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier this way

```
preg_split("#/#", ltrim("example/example2/example3/etc/", "/"));
```