# Getting the path of a file in PHP three levels up from the current directory

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to access a folder three levels up from my working directory with `file_put_contents()`.  Here is my working directory.

```
Users/myMac/Sites/mini-configurator/miniconfig/application/controllers
```

I need to get to the 'mini-configurator' folder and then into a subfolder of that called 'mc'.  I can get the path of the file in PHP with `dirname(__FILE__)`.  How do I use that to get to the mini-configurator folder.

I tried `dirname('../../../ . __FILE__)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290146/how-to-split-a-path-properly-in-php

Comment: That'll work.  Thanks, Deepak.

Answer (score 2):

did you try

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../";
```

Comment: No, I need to navigate up three levels from the working directory to save a file.

Comment: @shummel7845 that's exactly what this does.

Answer (score 1):

Having dealt with this recently, I've found something like:

```
$path = dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)));
```

a little easier to read. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an absolute directory structure:

```
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/../.../...."; 
//in the quotes just set it to the path from the root directory
```